# updating field based on another field with arcpy.da.updateCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

My code is very simple and it should work, but it doesn't. Perhaps another set of eyes can solve my issue...
I created new field (this part works), then look up value of another field and depending on it, update field "Surface" with either 3 or 2 (in my case value stays "null", but no error).

here the code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

field5 = "SURFACE"

arcpy.AddField_management(input_fc, field5, "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "","", "Dm_VehicleCapacity")

fields2 = ['VehicleCarryingCapacityCurrent', 'SURFACE']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(input_fc, fields2) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if fields2[0] == 9:
            fields2[1] = 3
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            fields2[1] = 2
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 6):

you use fields2 (the list of field names) instead of row (the actual record). You should query and modify the row of your cursor (with row[0] the value of 'VehicleCarryingCapacityCurrent' and row[1] the value of 'SURFACE')

```
fields2 = ('VehicleCarryingCapacityCurrent', 'SURFACE')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(input_fc, fields2) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == 9:
            row[1] = 3
        else:
            row[1] = 2
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: That actually didn't work. Comes up with an error.

Comment: what is your error message ?